# Как в Laravel задать сортировку, чтобы заданный id шёл первым, а затем остальные по убыванию?

Tags: laravel, сортировка

Код выводит одну статью на странице с пагинацией. Страницы (id) = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

```
  $first = 3;

  return Article::query()
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->paginate(1);
```

Как в запросе поменять порядок сортировки так, чтобы сначала отобразилась запись с id = 3, а уже затем по убыванию, минуя повторное 3?
Т.е. записи должны выводиться в таком порядке: 3, 5, 4, 2, 1.

Comment: Сама Лара так делать не умеет. Но можно добавить конструкцию `ORDER BY FIELD` (если это мускул), [пример запроса тут](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109126/198711). Получается, нужно сделать через query builder примерно так: `$builder->orderByRaw("FIELD(id,3);")`. Попробуйте. Вот еще ответ, [там тот же принцип](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27491995/9435985)

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Действительно работает! Только добавил DESC и убрал в конце точку с запятой! ) `->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, 3) DESC")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstElem = collect(DB::table('table')->find($first));
$another = collect(BD::table('table')->where('id', '!=', $first)->orderByDesc('id')->get());
$firstElem = $firstElem->merge($another); // соединяет
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]